# Ctrl+P shows empty content in Print Preview in Chrome Browser for PDF file

Tags: google-chrome, printing, pdf-viewer

In Chrome browser using window.open(),we open PDF file in separate tab. From the opened PDF file we are able to see contents in the print preview using right click then print option. But if we do ctrl+P then empty page appears in the print preview.

I am looking for the solution to show actual contents in the print preview if we do ctrl+P